# Disable a button with multiple layers of conditions in html-file

Tags: angular

Im sorry, i didnt really know how to call this, thats why i couldn't find anything on google too.
Basically i want to try the following which doesn't seem to work

```
<button [disabled]="condition1 || condition2 || (condition3 && condition4)">Save</button>
```

Condition1 and condition2 are working fine but if condition3 and 4 are met, the button still is active

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: What is condition3 and condition4? Please provide some context

Comment: The above button will be disabled if condition1 is true or condition2 is true or condition3 and condition4 both true.

Comment: What do you mean by _condition3 and 4 are met_ ?

Comment: btw. is it better to handle those things in the .ts code instead of in the component.
Like `isActive` as boolean and in the `ngOnInit() { this.isActive = ... }`

Comment: If `condition1` is true then the rest aren't even evaluated.

Comment: share your condition logic and condition wise output @NicholasK

Comment: please add input and expected output

Comment: A wild guess: either condition3 or condition4 is a check if the array is empty. Please be aware, that empty arrays are still truthy. You need to check the length of the array. Empty object `{}` are also truthy for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function to achieve this

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kulnej)

**in .ts**

```
   getCondition():boolean{
      return this.condition1 || this.condition2 || (this.condition3 && this.condition4);
    }
```

**.html**

```
<button [disabled]="getCondition()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the four condition written in **.ts** file

```
    cond3 = true;
    cond2 = false;
    cond1 = false;
    cond4 = true;
```

Here is code in **.html** file

```
<button [disabled]="(cond1 || cond2) || ((cond3 && cond4))">
```

**Case : 1**
If cond3 and cond4 both are true then it will satisfy the condition and put the button false . 
If any one in cond3 and cond4 are false then it will not statisfy the condition and make button clickable

Hope you get the answer .